# Как сделать прокручеваемый Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity

Мне надо чтобы Fragment растягивался до размеров экрана, а если в него что-то не влезло, его можно было прокрутить. Я попробовал сделать так.

Activity в которую вставляется фрагмент.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".components.login.ui.LogInActivity"
    android:id="@+id/log_in_activity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</LinearLayout>
```

Сам фрагмент

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".components.login.ui.SignUpFirstTypeFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:paddingBottom="30dp"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_bitmap"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:id="@+id/logo_image"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/sign_up_types_account"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
            android:contentDescription="@string/logo_description"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/sign_up_types_account"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/logo_image"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/sign_up_buttons">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#f50707"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:id="@+id/login_email_alert"/>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/your_email"
                android:background="@drawable/border_style"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/login_email"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#f50707"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:id="@+id/login_password_alert"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/your_password"
                android:background="@drawable/border_style"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:id="@+id/login_password"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/sign_up_buttons"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/sign_up_types_account"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/log_in"
                android:backgroundTint="#FFB803"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:id="@+id/button_login"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/back_arrow"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:id="@+id/login_back_arrow"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Но на выходе у меня получается вот-это
[image: Картинка приложения]
Почему? Что я сделал не так?

P.S затем это будет регистрация, и полей ввода будет больше. Поэтому нужен скролл. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Для ConstraintLayout надо поставить высоту wrap_content, чтобы работал скролл. И фон вам, наверное, лучше переместить в ScrollView

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо, помогло. Еще, как я понял, ScrollView дружит только с LinearLayout

Comment: так же constraintlayout - контейнер, который был разработан специально для одноуровневой верстки, помещать в него другие контейнеры, как LinearLayout, это как бриться топором - можно, но не многие оценят. Вы уж либо компонуйте классическими контейнерами, то есть корневой тоже LinearLayout, либо используйте ConstraintLayout так, как его задумали использовать, то есть виджеты связываются между собой констрайнтами.

Answer (score 1):

Ваша проблема в том, что ScrollView сам по себе не хочет занимать весь доступный объем. Чтобы это случилось надо ему поставить атрибут android:fillViewport="true"

Ну и как вам уже сказали в комментариях - не используйте ConstraintLayout для умещения переменного числа объектов. Внутри ScrollView редко нужно что-то, кроме LinearLayout, в вашем случае точно нужно использовать его